# Compress videos to a specified file size?

Tags: video, conversion, video-conversion

I have 3 video files that are 50 MB, 100 MB and 150 MB.

I want to compress each to 25 MB each.

I understand the larger videos will sacrifice more quality.

**Is there any software that can compress videos to a specified file size?**

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much any encoder can do this. Handbrake is probably the easiest. You will want to use the 'target file size' and 2-pass options.